# Angularjs ng-repeat with comma separated but last element

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of elements (tags) that I want to show comma separated but last one. But it´s not working. Commas are not displayed.

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in post.tags"><a href="">{{tag.name | translate}}</a><span ng-show="{{!$last}}">, </span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng-hide="$last"` instead. You don't need `{{` and `}}` in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the similar example and looks like the problem is with a filter 'translate'

```
{{tag.name | translate}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kikill/re4x99ra/

Answer (score 0):

All right,

I finally solved it with: `{{{true: '', false: ', '}[$last]}}`

Comment: actually {{ }} should be removed. Then, it should be ok. Besides, I suggest you to use a nice IDE like sublime to detect such typo mistakes